# CiviCRM Search not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Here is what is going on.

I'm trying to do a search within my CiviCRM, however, I'm getting the error message:

One of parameters (value: sort_name) is not of the type MysqlColumnNameOrAlias.

So I'm looking at the following log and one of the messages in the log:

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in require_once() (line 218 of /home3/isrcus/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php).

I'm using Drupal 7. Not sure what version of CiviCRM I'm using..

Comment: version of civi should be at the bottom of any civi admin page, or under Admin > System Status. Also if you can add any history about was this working fine, then broke, and if so what other changes may have coincided with that break

Comment: I think that would be a fairly old version of civi as that error is a php 7.4 notice which was fixed a long time back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of folks are responding in the comments, but I'll try to give a non-technical answer.

**Short Answer**: You need to upgrade CiviCRM.

**Longer Answer**: CiviCRM is written in a programming language called PHP.  Over time, new versions of PHP come out.  CiviCRM must be updated in response.

It sounds like your webhost upgraded your PHP version to one that didn't exist when your version of CiviCRM was released.  So any issues introduced by the newer PHP are affecting your experience.  Newer versions of CiviCRM support newer versions of PHP, so you must upgrade CiviCRM.  If you can control your PHP version yourself (some webhosts allow this, others don't) you can try downgrading PHP as a temporary measure, but that's not particularly secure or sustainable.